# How to match the keywords in a given sentence to create Schematron expressions XSLT 2.0 or 3.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have been dealing with an issue for a while that is for a multiple given sentences and keywords, I need to match the keywords and find them in the sentence and create another string,based on the order of the sentence for each keyword.

Thus, the keywords list do not have to follow the same order as in sentence. But the order should match as it is in the sentence. Hope it is clear.

The XML Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
<LIST>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <MESSAGE>Cats(13) are "lovely" or "beautiful" and Dogs(10) are "loyal" or "friendly".</MESSAGE>
</LIST>
<LIST>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <MESSAGE>Horses(11) are not a "good" option and Pigs(12) are okay</MESSAGE>
</LIST>
<ADJS>
    <ADJ>lovely</ADJ>
</ADJS>
<ADJS>
    <ADJ>friendly</ADJ>
</ADJS>
<ADJS>
    <ADJ>beautiful</ADJ>
</ADJS>
<ADJS>
    <ADJ>loyal</ADJ>
</ADJS>
<ADJS>
    <ADJ>good</ADJ>
</ADJS>
 <ADJS>
    <ADJ>okay</ADJ>
</ADJS>
<KEYWORDS>
    <ID>10</ID>
    <KEYWORD>Dogs</KEYWORD>
</KEYWORDS>
<KEYWORDS>
    <ID>11</ID>
    <KEYWORD>Horses</KEYWORD>
</KEYWORDS>
<KEYWORDS>
    <ID>12</ID>
    <KEYWORD>Pigs</KEYWORD>
</KEYWORDS>
<KEYWORDS>
    <ID>13</ID>
    <KEYWORD>Cats</KEYWORD>
</KEYWORDS>
<KEYWORDS>
    <ID>14</ID>
    <KEYWORD>aquarium</KEYWORD>
</KEYWORDS>
<KEYWORDS>
    <ID>b</ID>
    <KEYWORD>Fishes</KEYWORD>
</KEYWORDS>
<OP>
    <SYNTAX>and</SYNTAX>
</OP>
<OP>
    <SYNTAX>or</SYNTAX>
</OP>
<OP>
    <SYNTAX>are not</SYNTAX>
</OP>
<OP>
    <SYNTAX>are</SYNTAX>
</OP>
```

XSLT that I kinda tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:function name="functx:contains-any-of" as="xs:boolean">
    <xsl:param name="arg" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:param name="searchStrings" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="
            some $searchString in $searchStrings
                satisfies contains($arg, $searchString)
            "/>
</xsl:function>
<xsl:template match="ROOT">
    <xsl:variable name="keyID" select="//KEYWORDS/ID"/>
    <xsl:variable name="keyName" select="//KEYWORDS/KEYWORD"/>
    <xsl:variable name="keyOp" select="//OP/SYNTAX"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="//MESSAGE">
        <xsl:variable name="message" select="node()"/>
        <xsl:if test="functx:contains-any-of($message, $keyID)">

            <xsl:element name="test">
                <xsl:value-of select="$keyName"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$keyOp"/>
            </xsl:element>

            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output:

```
<test>Cats = ('lovely','beautiful') and Dogs = ('loyal','friendly')</test>
<test>Horses != 'good' or Pigs = 'okay'</test>
```

The thing is that, everything here is transformed from Excel file, what i am trying to do is to have automatic transformation. from Excel to Schematron. in this part, I already converted the Excel to XML.

Now, I am trying to get Xpath definitions from the sentences, by using the keywords. Because, these keywords are dynamic. If it chances in excel, has to change all the way down to schematron.

I need to find those keywords in the sentences, by the order of sentence. and operators and adjectives as well. So I can create expressions as I tried to show in the expected output.

I cant change the order or the structure of the sentence. The main idea here is to create an Xpath definition out of the sentences.

**UPDATE**

So I learned from one of the posts of Martin Honnen that in XSLT 2.0, `$name = ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Cindy')` is possible.

**UPDATE-2**

```
<xsl:variable name="operator" select="$btbg/node()/SimpleCodeList/Row/Value[@ColumnRef = 'DictionaryEntryName']/SimpleValue/text()"/>
<xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="w" select="tokenize(., '\s+')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$w[position() &gt; index-of($w, $w[. = $operator][1])]"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

I was thinking about this idea to put the sentence in a loop after it finds the keyword till the end. But also could not make it work. `$operator` paramater is coming from another XML file. If i do it in this way, I cant get the value recursively. It reads all the operators or any other parameters in the XML.

I want to choose nodes one by one and find them in the sentence. then Cut the sentence there after reading the value, and put the sentence into loop again for the next keyword.

How can I overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the expected output like `<test>Cats are "lovely" and Cats are "beautiful" and Dogs are "loyal" and Dogs are "friendly"</test>` Schematron? In your question title and in the text you talk about creating Schematron.

Comment: I left a challenging part for myself to change those text operators to "=" "and" "!=" etc. The part I need to create is to test part for schematron validations by the sentences. Sorry if it is confusing. At the end finaly look would be, Cats="lovely" or Cats="lovely" and Dogs="loyal" or Dogs="friendly"

Comment: Hi Martin, Any ideas ? @MartinHonnen

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you want to achieve, for instance why does `Horses(11) are not a "good" option` translate into `Horses = 'good'`, given that the sentence says `not a good option`? In general analysing human language with program code seems quite a challenge, something that is beyond my abilities and beyond of what can be achieved in a answer to a stackoverflow post. As you do use XSLT 2, you have more than `contains` with `tokenize` and `matches` and also `xsl:analyze-string` but regular expressions are not as complex as is human language.

Comment: It is my bad, sorry for the conflicts really. it was really hard to create an example. I fix many things. It is supposed to be != if it is are not of course. In general, the idea is to translate some of the keywords to operators. but the whole process of reading each word has to be in order of the sentence. Thanks for the answers

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen regarding to your answer, I am not trying to analyze it. just matching keywords that appears in the string with the order. Do you think that, adding the rest of the sentence after the keyword found and repeating it till we get all keywords at the end, makes sense? how could be the approach? Thanks a lot